# how to change datetime value through timezone

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, timezone

I have a XML file with datetime value `2013-11-28T14:48:25.423-08:00`.

My server's time zone is `UTC +08:00 Irkutsk`.

Problem is:

When I read that `XML` using `DataSet.ReadXML()` and insert it into `MSSQL datatable`, the value shifted to my `timezone` and looks like `2013-11-29 06:48:25.423`.

But I need `timezone` unaware value which should look like `2013-11-28 14:48:25.423`.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: And this has to do with SQL Server how?  Please edit and tag appropriately, and you MUST show some code if you want help!

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't have anything to do with SQL Server, but rather with the behavior of `DataSet.ReadXML` in .NET.  I will assume C# for the answer.  (I have re-tagged your question as such)

A lot of what you're asking depends very much on the exact code that you are using, and what the data looks like.  For example, consider the following:

```csharp
var ds = new DataSet("MyDataSet");
var dt = ds.Tables.Add("MyDataTable");
dt.Columns.Add("MyDateTime", typeof (DateTime));

var startingDateTime = DateTime.Now;
dt.Rows.Add(startingDateTime);

var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
    ds.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

Debug.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

var ds2 = new DataSet();
using (var reader = new StringReader(sb.ToString()))
    ds2.ReadXml(reader, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);

var resultingDateTime = (DateTime) ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MyDateTime"];

Debug.WriteLine("");
Debug.WriteLine("Starting: {0} ({1})", startingDateTime, startingDateTime.Kind);
Debug.WriteLine("Ending:   {0} ({1})", resultingDateTime, resultingDateTime.Kind);
```

Debug Output:

```xml
<MyDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="MyDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="MyDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="MyDataTable">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="MyDateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <MyDataTable>
    <MyDateTime>2013-12-02T15:59:58.5209045-07:00</MyDateTime>
  </MyDataTable>
</MyDataSet>

Starting: 12/02/2013 15:59:58 (Local)
Ending:   12/02/2013 15:59:58 (Unspecified)
```

Because I included schema in the XML (using `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema` and `XmlReadMode.ReadSchema`) the data was properly deserialized as a `DateTime`.  The only problem you will have is that the `DateTimeKind` is not persisted.  If that is a concern, then consider using the `DateTimeOffset` type instead of a `DateTime`.

If you would please update your question with the specific code you are using to deserialize your XML, and a sample of the XML that works with that code, then perhaps I can provide a more direct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is easiest to fix when the data is written, if you can.

The issue is that 2013-11-28T14:48:25.423-08:00 has the timezone in it so when it is read it is interpreted and altered by the deserialization in the ReadXml method. Basically with the timezone it refers to a particular point in time whatever the local timezone is, whereas without, it refers to a particular hour of the clock.

If you are using `DataSet.WriteXML()` you can set the `DateTimeMode` property of the datetime columns you need to alter to `System.Data.DataSetDateTime.Unspecified` you may need to do this before the dataset is loaded with data. This changes the serialization when the XML is written.